# In JTS, when I do geometry.buffer(1).buffer(-1), will the resulting geometry be equivalent to the original?

Tags: java, geometry, buffer, jts

I was having problems while intersecting two geometries, getting a TopologyException probably due to a rounding error during the operation, then I read [this fix](http://www.mail-archive.com/jts-devel@lists.jump-project.org/msg00512.html) and tried a `buffer(0)` on both input geometries, but still without success. Then I tried `geo.buffer(1).buffer(-1)` and it worked.

Will these geometries be equivalent to the original ones?

Comment: This is the Java Topology Suite, I assume, not Java Transaction Service...

Comment: There you go, a few more tags should do the trick ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about JTS, but it can't be true in general.

Assume you have two shapes:

```
 XXX      XXX
 X X      XXX
 XXX      XXX
```

From my understanding a `buffer(1)` on both would result in roughly this:

```
XXXXX    XXXXX
XXXXX    XXXXX
XXXXX    XXXXX
XXXXX    XXXXX
XXXXX    XXXXX
```

Now `buffer(-1)` won't be able to produce two different results from those two shapes.

Effectively a `buffer()` operation looses information, so it can't be undone without re-adding that information from somewhere else.

Comment: This is correct, the shape will not be the same.  However you can use this to your advantage because buffering and unbuffering by very tiny amounts can be used to "smooth off" problematic areas on the geometries, such as slivers or tiny gaps.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think these geometries will be the same. By default behavior buffering a feature add vertices to it's original configuration, and there is no guarantee that the same vertices will be removed.

Try doing a very small buffer, a.buffer(0.00001), for instance (1/1000th mm, if coordinates in metric systems).

In PostGIS some issues are corrected by doing this.

Comment: I did this, but with a very small value. We are using geographic coordinates.

Comment: it should "correct" itself. GEOS and other GEOS based software works. If i'm not mistaken GEOS is based on a JTS port.

Comment: GEOS is indeed based on a JTS port.  There is also NTS, a C# port (though it is of an older JTS version).  PostGIS uses GEOS under the hood for many of its spatial operations.